# Average Hamming distance to nearest neighbor for uniformly sampled strings

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose you uniformly sample $n$ strings of length $l$ and with $k$ symbols in the alphabet. I'm looking to estimate, for any given string also of length $l$, the average Hamming distance to its nearest neighbor in this dataset.

I've seen lots of similar questions but never this exact one, but if the solution is well known I'd appreciate being pointed in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is well known, but my approach was as follows:

Let $X$ be the random variable in question (the minimum Hamming distance between the string $A$ and the bag of n strings $B_1, \cdots, B_n$). Let us also use $H(X, Y)$ to represent the hamming distance between $X$ and $Y$. Now, calculate $P(H(A, B_i) \geq x) = 1 - P(H(A, B_i) < x)$. Use that to calculate $P\left(\min_i (H(A, B_i)) \geq x\right)$, and  finally use Layer Cake Representation to get $$E[X] = \sum_{x=1}^l P\left(\min_i (H(A, B_i)) \geq x\right)$$

This gives a messy solution with a summation of a series, and I'm not sure if this can be manipulated into an elegant formula.